# iOS Swift: Parse Invalid Session Token Error

Tags: ios, swift, session, parse-platform, error-handling

I have a problem with the Error 209: Invalid session token. I just open the app like in the Parse Guide and if I delete the session in the web applet i get the Error 209. I want to catch this error and handle it but I don't know where the error occurs. Is it possible to catch all Parse errors or is there a way to find out where the error occurs?

Here is my code:

```
//Parse setup
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
    Parse.setApplicationId("xxx",
        clientKey: "xxx")
    PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

    PFUser.enableRevocableSessionInBackgroundWithBlock({(error: NSError?) in

        //enable the session errors
        if (error != nil)
        {
            NSLog(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
//get current user
    let user: PFUser = PFUser.currentUser()
```

I after getting the current user the application opens the start page with no action, but the error occurs anyway.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem by trying out every single line! Every contact with the Parse server leads to the error 209. The first contact with the server is the following line:

```
PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
```

There is a asynchronous command for this action so I found out there is the first error. It doesn't matter how you handle the occurring error it is logged every time without a command. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: So how do you fix it?

Comment: Sorry I haven't saw the post. I have rewritten the hole code and just checked if the token is valid after the first server contact. If this failed you know that the token is invalid because of the returning error. I think this is new in the new Parse version!

Answer (score 0):

Well I currently don't know if its the Problem, but please execute the get User inside the closure, because your "BackgroundBlock" may be return with the token after you ask for your user... So please try this

```
//Parse setup
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
    Parse.setApplicationId("xxx",
        clientKey: "xxx")
    PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

    PFUser.enableRevocableSessionInBackgroundWithBlock({(error: NSError?) in

        //enable the session errors
        if (error != nil)
        {
            NSLog(error!.localizedDescription)
        } else {
          //get current user
          let user: PFUser = PFUser.currentUser()
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The error 209 doesn't occur in this part of the source code. The completion handler of this method finishes without an error and the error 209 even occurs if I comment out the "PFUser.currentUser()" function. I don't know which part of the program causes the error.

Comment: Ok, well I couldn't solve this problem without any debugging possibility, could you comment out other parts of the code to find out where it happens and than post it here as an edit?